# Define ProxyPass with a wildcard

Tags: apache, proxy, proxypass

I have the following rule to proxy a sub-directory of my site to another host:

```
    <Location /somedir/>
            ProxyPass http://www.anothersite.com/somedir/
            ProxyPassReverse http://www.anothersite.com/somedir/
    </Location>
```

There are a number of other top level directories which I also need to ProxyPass. Is there a way to set up a group of items to match and then use them again in the ProxyPass line?

E.g.

```
    <Location /(somedir|foo|bar)/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into LocationMatch and ProxyMatch.